# Indexing a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of over 500s URLs that I have named in the following way:

```
url_1="https://www....."
url_2="https://www....."
url_3="https://www....."
```

and so on.

I am trying to put all of these URLs in a list, but I don't want to write the whole thing out. Is there a way to automatically generate an indexed list like this?

```
[url_1,url_2,url_3,...,url_500]
```

Comment: Generate it automatically... from what? Don't tell me you have 500 `url_x` variables.

Comment: Why don't you, instead of writing 500 `url_X` variables in your code, put them straight into a list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```
final_list = ["url_{}".format(i+1) for i in range(500)]
```

Output:

```
['url_1', 'url_2', 'url_3', 'url_4', 'url_5', 'url_6', 'url_7', 'url_8', 'url_9', 'url_10', 'url_11', 'url_12', 'url_13', 'url_14', 'url_15', 'url_16', 'url_17'...]
```

Or using the shorter, but less efficient, `map` function:

```
final_data = list(map(lambda x:"url_{}".format(x+1), range(500)))
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you.

Comment: @J.Smith if this answer helped you, please accept it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this
['url_%s'%x for x in range(500)]